# React Native modalize trying to have two always open destinations

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-modalize

I currently have a modal using React Native modalize. The modal is always open at 500 and when I swipe the modal up, it opens to 700. The functionality is currently working.

I am trying to add that when the always open modal at 500 is swiped down, the modal closes to 300.

How can I accomplish such a feature?

Here is my code:

```
function Screen() {
  const modal = React.createRef();

  return (
    <Modalize
      ref={modal}
      alwaysOpen={500}
      modalHeight={700}
      handlePosition="inside"
    >
      <View style={s.content}>
        <Text style={s.content__subheading}>
          {'Introduction'.toUpperCase()}
        </Text>
        <Text style={s.content__heading}>Always open modal!</Text>
        <Button
          name="Close to initial position"
          onPress={() => this.closeModal('alwaysOpen')}
        />
        <Button name="Close completely" onPress={this.closeModal} />
      </View>
    </Modalize>
  )
}

export default Screen;
```